# AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've the following room object which has Users as members.

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to find the Room that has only two specific members,

```
if Room.objects.filter(members__id=first.id).filter(members__id=second.id).exists():
                    rooms = Room.objects.filter(members__id=first.id).filter(members__id=second.id)
                    for room in rooms:
                        print(room.members.count)
                        if room.members.count == 2:
                            return Response({"Success": RoomSerializer(room).data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I know that there exists a Room object which has only two members. But I end up getting this error,

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `room.members.count` should be `room.members.count()`.

Comment: @Borut you can put this as an answer, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QuerySet count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) is a method (`type(room.members.count)` returns `<class 'method'>`) and should be called as such. Just change

```
room.members.count
```

to

```
room.members.count()
```

and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As the exception said, at the end of the view, always return a response. In you current code, if the logics does not match, then it returns None.So, update the code like this:

```
if Room.objects.filter(members__id=first.id).filter(members__id=second.id).exists():
                rooms = Room.objects.filter(members__id=first.id).filter(members__id=second.id)
                for room in rooms:
                    print(room.members.count)
                    if room.members.count == 2:
                        return Response({"Success": RoomSerializer(room).data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
return Response({"Failed": True}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) # <-- Return a bad request maybe at the end if all logic fails
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If the code already enters the if block then I've already determined I've a valid reponse. The correct answer is in the comments.

Comment: as you have shown partial code and there is responses returned only under if condition, it can be assumed that there could be a logic which might not comply with the conditions, in that case, the code did not have any return response. That is part I have focused. and I did not see the `count`, good catch by borut :)